# Computers communicate in binary. what if we convert the text to binary ourselves. will it take computer more bits to send this converted text?

Tags: text, encoding, binary, computer-science, communication

One of my friend had his birthday today. I thought sending 'Happy Birthday' would be a cliché so i had this idea of encoding the message to binary.

Happy Birthday first changed to ASCII and became '7297112112121326610511411610410097121' and '7297112112121326610511411610410097121' changed to binary and became '0100100001100001011100000111000001111001001000000100001001101001011100100111010001101000011001000110000101111001'.

Now the Original 'Happy Birthday' had 14 characters including space and sending it would require 14*8bit=112bit as ASCII is a 8bit code. Now since I changed 'Happy Birthday' to '0100100001100001011100000111000001111001001000000100001001101001011100100111010001101000011001000110000101111001' which is of length 112 and would require 112*8bit=896 bits to send.

If anyone knows about this stuff let me know if i am thinking correct or are there many loopholes in the above concept. If i am correct then i think we should leave the computer's work on computer.

Comment: 1. You need to get out more. 2. You definitely need to get out more. 3. You would be sending binary with "happy birthday". 4. You message is an ASCII version of a binary number. (ps you might be sending those characters as unicode)

Comment: @imox You should get your computer to know that you have already converted the message to binary, else it'd consider it to be a normal character array (it doesn't read your message and try to understand what you are doing with it) and try to covert that to binary (again) himself!